# JAVA ASM conditionals

Tags: java-bytecode-asm

I want to create following java method using JAVA ASM.

```
        public Object myeq(String one) {
            if (one.equalsIgnoreCase("ABC")) {
                return this.one;
            } else if (one.equalsIgnoreCase("BCD")) {
                return this.two;
            } else {
                return this.three;
            }
        }
```

Following is the -p output for the sample

```
  public java.lang.Object myeq(java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_1
         1: ldc           #2                  // String ABC
         3: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/String.equalsIgnoreCase:(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
         6: ifeq          14
         9: aload_0
        10: getfield      #4                  // Field one:Ljava/lang/String;
        13: areturn
        14: aload_1
        15: ldc           #5                  // String BCD
        17: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/String.equalsIgnoreCase:(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
        20: ifeq          28
        23: aload_0
        24: getfield      #6                  // Field two:Ljava/lang/Float;
        27: areturn
        28: aload_0
        29: getfield      #7                  // Field three:I
        32: invokestatic  #8                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
        35: areturn
      LineNumberTable:
        line 14: 0
        line 15: 9
        line 16: 14
        line 17: 23
        line 19: 28
      StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 2
        frame_type = 14 /* same */
        frame_type = 13 /* same */
```

As i am new to ASM would want to know how do i move ahead with doing this and if there are any sample that could guide me on the same.

Comment: Try [ASMifier](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/util/ASMifier.html#main(java.lang.String%5B%5D))

Comment: Not sure, how it will help me to write else if

Comment: Use your class file as input for ASMifier. It outputs java code that would output that class file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Got it. It helped a lot. Example on how to use it can be found below. https://martin.uy/blog/asmifier-from-java-bytecode-to-programmable-bytecode/